# Python: How can I save the output of eval() in a variable?

Tags: python

I'm new in the world of Python.
My question is: How can i save the output of eval() in a variable?

```
# CODE
var = eval(print("Heyo"))
message = f"{var}"

# RESULT
None
```

I tried with a numeral expression: 1+1 and the output is 2.
I need the output to be: Heyo (in this case)

What can I do?

Comment: You have saved the output of eval to a variable, `eval(None)` is None

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture the standard output of a command?

Comment: `print` returns `None`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eval will execute whatever is inside the string you give it as input, which means your print statement will print to the standard input. One way you can work around this is to redirect the `stdout` into a variable before you call eval.

```py
from io import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

eval("print('Heyo')")

sys.stdout = old_stdout

message = mystdout.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 2):

theres no return for a print statement?

```
var = eval("2")
message = f"{var}"

print(message)
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the problem.
I'm using this to create a code "executor" in a telegram message, using Pyrogram.
The script takes a snippet of code like, for example, print("Heyo") and tries to return it on the message.

Comment: @LelloDev so an python eval function for telegram?

Answer (score 0):

eval() evaluates the string as a python code. now if there is any return value, that will be stored in the `var` variable. here with your code, the print statement returns `None` after execution. so you are getting None as message.

for example:

if you run the below code, you will get 500:

```
def something(): 
    return 500

var = eval("something()")

print(var)
```

```
output
500
```