# discord.py outputing the result of eval

Tags: python, discord.py

recently I've started making a bot in python. part of this bot requires me to send the result of an eval into the chat. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, this is the code I have currently

```
sMessage = "print('hello world')"
var1 = eval(sMessage)
await message.channel.send(var1)
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Thanks

edit: Fix typo in example code, the error this code gives is "400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message "

Comment: What is your desired result and actual result and are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209896/1935238) which redirects `stdout`. As mentioned below `eval()` does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using the `"` multiple times without denoting when you want to display the character vs use it to terminate your string.
You want to add a `\` before special characters to denote they're to be displayed rather than terminate your string

```py
sMessage = "print(\"hello world\")"
```

Another solution would be to swap the double quotes to single quotes

```py
sMessage = "print('hello world')"
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: unfortunately, this still throws a "400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message"

Comment: Oh. It's because Eval() doesn't return anything. It just evaluates the string the prints the results to console. So var1 is never assigned.

Comment: Oh. so, how would i go about getting the result of the eval to send?

Answer (score 0):

See its wrong ,you missed a quote so it should be

```
sMessage = "print('hello world')"
var1 = eval(sMessage)
await message.channel.send(var1)
```

Be carefull next, (I am not scolding you)

Comment: That was a typo on my end as the actual sMessage is a variable from input, I used "hello world" as a placeholder as not to overexplain the code, even if you attempt to use the code you have listed, the bot does not send the result of print("hello world")

This throws an error stating the following "400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message "